# Working with AWS Workflows: Waiting for a promise to finish before executing a function.

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-swf

I am trying to get acquainted with AWS Workflows and Promises.
I have a list:

```
List<Promise<ClassA>> classA= someSet.stream()
                  .filter()
                  .map(/*Insert call activity*/)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

Promise<Void> waitForPromises = new AndPromise(
              doSomething(classA),
              .
              .Some other functions);

facts = /*do Some processing*/
Promise<ClassB<EnumA>> actions = ActivityB.evaluate(facts, waitForPromises);
performActions(actions, facts, classA);
```

evaluate function:

```
evaluate(Facts facts, Promise<?>... waitFor)
```

Now if I wasn't modifying the values in classA, I could have made the definition of performActions something like this:
`performActions(Promise<ClassB<EnumA>> actions, Facts facts, @Wait List<Promise<ClassA>> classA)`;

But now I need to ensure that before performActions is called `classA` has the updated values due to the actions performed in `doSomething`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
List<Promise<ClassA>> classA= someSet.stream()
              .filter()
              .map(/*Insert call activity*/)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

Promise<List<ClassA>> somethingP = doSomething(classA)
Promise<Void> waitForPromises = new AndPromise(
          somethingP,
          .
          .Some other functions);

facts = /*do Some processing*/
Promise<ClassB<EnumA>> actions = ActivityB.evaluate(facts, waitForPromises);

performActions(actions, facts, somethingP);
```

where signature of perfomActions is:

```
performActions(Promise<ClassB<EnumA>> actions, Facts facts,
              Promise<List<ClassA>> somethingP);
```

*Edit: Updated doSomething to return Promise<List<ClassA>>*

Comment: I didn't follow you with the mutation. In the example you gave, would somethingP contain a List? Would it be possible to give your suggestion in code. I am not able to follow. I require the contents of classA in performActions. Did you mean somethingP will contain that ?

Comment: How do I retrieve the contents of classA from somethingP ?

Comment: Updated code to return Promise<List> from doSomething.